# Equivariant cohomology, identity

Tags: differential-geometry, equivariant-cohomology

I'm studying equivariant cohomology on three references:

1. [Szabo's review about equivariant localization (S);](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9608068)
2. [Libine's note on equivariant cohomology (L);](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3615)
3. Berline, Getzler, Vigne's book "Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators", Springer (BGV).

I'm deriving all formulas by myself. I face two problems:

1. In (S) when he derive (2.83) he uses a commutator while (L), in the longest formula below Definition 34 writes

$$
i_X\nabla + \nabla i_X.
$$

I agree with (L) because it's just the square:

$$
(\nabla - i_X)^2,
$$

so why (S) put the commutator? (BGV) seems to agree with (S).

2. Then I compute

$$
\begin{align}
(i_X\nabla + \nabla i_X)\alpha 
& = i_X(d\alpha + \omega\wedge\alpha) + (d + \omega)i_X\alpha\\
& = i_Xd\alpha + i_X\omega\wedge\alpha - \omega\wedge i_X\alpha +  di_X\alpha + \omega\wedge i_X\alpha\\
& = (i_Xd\alpha + \omega(X)\alpha) +di_X\alpha\\
& = \nabla_X\alpha + di_X\alpha
\end{align}.
$$

So I get an extra $di_X\alpha$. This must be correct because also (BGV) write (page 211)

$$
[\nabla,i_X]=\nabla_X
$$

which is, apart for the mysterious commutator instead anticommutator, the same formula.

Comment: Anyone writing a commutator in this business almost certainly means a supercommutator (so either a commutator or an anticommutator depending on the degrees of what's involved).

Comment: Yes, but in this case all is bosonic so it's a real commutator!